# potato and carrot dumpling,how would you make it diabetic frendly?

Tags: potatoes, dumplings, carrots, dietary-restriction

not sure how to put this recipe up for others to cross-reference but it's on food.com if anyone wants to find it. the recipes name is carrot and potato dumplings and my question is how would you make it diabetic friendly? I'm honestly not sure myself, thussly my question here.  Also I'm diabetic myself, so ANY advice as to how to make it diabetic friendly would be nice! I'm not sure how to make it better for diabetics in anyone's interested.

Comment: I'd recommend a diabetic tag for questions like this.

Comment: You might alter it slightly, substituting cauliflower, mashed, and add a beaten egg white to bind before steaming.

Comment: acturally that does make some sense @Dorothy

Comment: We are not a health site, which is why this question was closed. Medical issues should be discussed in places that are designed for that subject.

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed. Come on guys, there are regularly questions asking for low carb substitutes, why close this one? But to the question you can finely grate them and wash off most of the starch and see how it goes. Maybe add some binder e.g. egg or thickener e.g. xanthan to keep it together. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I referenced the recipe which has only the two ingredients, grated potatoes and carrots, and seasoning. For the potato, substitute cauliflower, cooked until very soft, mashed. Fold in the carrots and a beaten egg white to bind the mixture before steaming, rather than the boiling option.